# Rails: Adding migration to add an array (default empty)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to add a column called share to one of my resources.
The idea is that users can upload documents and share them with other (specific) users, and the array contains the emails of those that the user wants to share with.

I tried adding a migration with the code

```
class AddShareToDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :documents, :share, :array, :default => []
  end
end
```

But when I open up rails console in the command prompt, it says that share:nil and user.document.share.class is NilClass.

Creating a new array in the rails console sandbox by typing

```
newarray = []
```

says that newarray.class is Array.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Postgres and want its array type?

Comment: I believe I am using SQLite. I have PostgreSQL installed but I don't think I am using it for this application. I want to add a variable called "share" to "document" and I want "share"'s type to be an array.

Comment: If either of these solutions worked for you, you should accept the answer that worked best. Same goes for any other questions you have asked. It makes it more clear to anyone else who runs into your question 6mo from now what worked and what didn't. If neither worked, but you figured it out yourself, you should post what you did and accept it.

Comment: I haven't fully implemented either solution yet. There was another problem that came up that needed to be taken care of. And in the mean time, I am trying to figure out how to add a join table (since this concept is new to me). But rest assured, I will mark the answer that works for me. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Rails 4 the PostgreSQL Array data type

In terminal

```
$ rails generate migration AddTagsToProduct tags:string
```

Migration file:

```
class AddTagsToProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :tags, :string, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

https://coderwall.com/p/sud9ja/rails-4-the-postgresql-array-data-type

Answer (score 9):

if you want support all databases you must serialize the array in a String

```rb
class Documents < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :share
end

class AddShareToDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   add_column :documents, :share, :string, :default => []
 end 
end
```

In case of Postgresql and array datatype I found https://coderwall.com/p/sud9ja

Comment: Thanks for this. But I just tried to rollback my last migration and I am getting the "undefined method 'to_sym' for nil class" error. I've been trying to google the solution to this to no avail. Any help on this? So I can't even undo my last migration to serialize the array.

Comment: Can you delete the database? `rake db:drop db:create` then change your migration as I described and run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: rake db:drop doesn't work. "Couldn't drop db/development.sqlite3 : #<Errno::EACCES: Permission Denied" and "Couldn't drop db/test.sqlite3 : #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory"

Comment: @user2669464, To undo a migration, there are a couple ways. You can rewrite your migration with up and down. Or you can make a new migration to remove the column. rails g migration remove_share_from_documents - then a rake:db:migrate - And you can remove the migration file if you'd like with rails d migration remove_share_from_documents - and you can do the same with the original after you've removed what you wanted. rails d migration add_share_to documents

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not normally a type to be stored in a database. As michelemina points out, you can serialize them into a string and store them, if the type of the data in the array is simple (strings, int, etc). For your case of emails, you could do this.

If, on the other hand, you want to be able to find all of the User objects that a document was shared with, there are better ways of doing this. You will want a "join table". In your case, the join-table object may be called a Share, and have the following attributes:

```
class Share
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :document
end
```

Then, in your Document class,

```
has_many :shares
has_many :users, :through => :shares
```

As far as generating the migration, this may be hacky, but you could create a new migration that changes the type to "string" (Edit: correct code):

```
class AddShareToDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :documents, :share, :string
  end
  def down
    change_column :documents, :share, :array, :default => []
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I'll give it a try once I get my migrations to work again. I didn't know about the :through association. When you mentioned changing the type to "string", were you referring to the class Share? In your migration code, I don't see how that turns it into a string type.

Comment: Sorry, lazy adapting on my part. What I meant to show was edited in. Hope this works.