# Ruby on Rails - Adding arrays to column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

If I have a Playlist model, how can I push arrays into a column?

```
#<Playlist id: 1, title: "This is a playlist", songs_ids: 1>
```

And want to push arrays to the `songs_ids` column what do I have to do?

This is how the `songs_ids` column look like

```
add_column :playlists, :songs_ids, :integer, array: true, default: []
```

I've tried updating the attributes and adding annother id of a song to it, but I have no luck with it either:

```
Playlist.find(1).update_attribute(songs_ids: [1, 2])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: Adding migration to add an array (default empty)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937792/rails-adding-migration-to-add-an-array-default-empty)

Comment: Are you serialising the array in your model class?

`serialize :song_ids, Array` in `Playlist.rb`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

Comment: @muistooshort I am using mysql database for development and postgres for production

Comment: AFAIK MySQL doesn't support array columns so your `songs_ids` is just an `int`. There are so many differences between MySQL and PostgreSQL that ActiveRecord will not help you with that developing on MySQL and deploying on PostgreSQL is madness. Develop and test with PostgreSQL if that's what you're deploying on. Rails/ActiveRecord doesn't offer any useful support for database portability beyond that absolute basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Postgresql you can simply use the `update_all` method to update array columns in your model.

```
Playlist.where(id: 1).update_all(songs_ids: [1,2])
```

Note it won't work with `Playlist.find(1)...`.

Using Mysql you can consider to [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) to do this you must use a string type column.

```
 def change
    add_column :playlists, :songs_ids, :string
  end
```

Then specify the attribute which to serialize in your model.

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base 
    serialize :songs_ids, Array 
end
```

Then you can test pushing any value to it.

```
playlist = Playlist.first
playlist.songs_ids << 1
=> [1]
playlist.save
playlist.songs_ids << 2
=> [2]
playlist.save
playlist.songs_ids
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Tested in Postgresql this works, on Mysql it doesn't, this one keeps the `songs_ids` attribute as `nil` after the operation.

Comment: It doesn't work even if I serialize because as you've mentioned I think it's to do with the database, and I'm guessing that's the only workaround for this?