# How to add multiple values to one column by using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A small question about rails console. I am using Ruby 2.6.0, Rails 5.2.3. I created a `countries` table and a `users` table.

I use `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` in the Country model and `has_and_belongs_to_many :countries` in the User model. I also created `country_users` table following the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). I want to make multiple values for `country_id` in `users` table. I think it is about adding array into one column.

I already have two records in `users` table. I want to know how can I use `rails c` to add more values to `country_id` column in `users` table.

Example:
Two records I had in `users` table:

```
    <User id: 1, email: "test01@france.com", created_at: "2019-05-21 12:36:08", updated_at: "2019-05-21 12:49:08",countryid: 1, regionid: 1>
    <User id: 2, email: "test02@france.com", created_at: "2019-05-21 12:36:18", updated_at: "2019-05-21 12:49:28",countryid: 2, regionid: 2>
```

How to add '2' into `country_id` column for first user via console?

Comment: you mean that in coutryid column you want array of countryid?

Comment: If a user can have more than a country, you need a join table. See has many through.

Comment: Usually (by default) many-to-many in Rails is implemented via intermediate join table - see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association for details. It is theoretically possible to do it via embedding (keeping an array of ids for example), but this way has numerous disadvantages and goes against conventions so it might (and will) be painful to maintain with Rails.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear description. I use 'has_and_belongs_to_many :users' in country model and so as user model. I also create 'country_user' table following guide 'https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html' . I want to make multiple values for 'countryid' in user table. Is it possible to use 'rails c'? I think it is about adding array into one column. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how the relationships are stored in your database.

If you assign an object a parent_id, in your case a country ID, it can only ever have one of these, meaning it can't be used for 'has_and_belongs_to_many' relationships.

You say you've made a join table which should be called country_users (or user_countries). Each of these records will have a country ID and a user ID, which establishes a link between those two records. If you want to establish a relationship like this in console, try:

```
country = Country.find(2)
user = User.find(1)
user.countries << country
```

This will create a new record in your join table, with a User ID of 1 and a country ID of 2, and mean when you call `user.countries` it will include the one you just assigned.

Comment: Thank you for clear reply. My understanding is: I misuse parent-child relationship and joint table. if country and user tables are both child tables, I can use a joint table like 'countries_users' to record all their relationships. If I make user table as a parent table and country table as a child table, I cannot use joint table. But I can add "countryid" column to user table(parent table) and add multiple country id as an array in it. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Did not get you propery, you want Array of Contry id in User table?

Comment: Yep! I know I need to set column as 'array: true' according to 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937792/rails-adding-migration-to-add-an-array-default-empty'. But how to add integer array into table by using rails c?

Comment: @landy, you don't need `country_id` column in `users` table at all, you only need a joint table here. With it you can query `User.first.countries` and get all countries for first user