# How do I migrate an indexed PostgreSQL string column to an indexed array of strings using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In our database we currently have a table with a String `country` column. This stores a single country code (e.g. `US`). The `country` column has an index. We now need to store multiple country codes in the column, so we want to convert it to a PostgreSQL String array. My current migration code is

```rb
  def change
    reversible do |direction|
      change_table :product do |table|
        direction.up do
          table.remove_index(:country)
          table.rename :country, :countries
          table.change :countries, :string, array: true
          table.index :countries
        end

        direction.down do
          table.remove_index(:countries)
          table.change :countries, :string, array: false
          table.rename :countries, :country
          table.index :country
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

however when I run the migration I get the error

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "countries" cannot be cast automatically to type character varying[]
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING countries::character varying[]"
```

and I am not sure how to specify how I want the conversion to be performed.

I would like to know how to change my migration so that

1. The `countries` column is an array
2. The `countries` column is indexed
3. The existing string value of the `country` column is saved into the array

or in other words, so that

```rb
country: 'US'
```

becomes

```rb
countries: ['US']
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this in a Rails migration without using SQL, which the error message generously assisted with. How is the array to be meaningfully indexed? Are there any constraints on the country values? Instead of changing the column to an array, consider creating a new table, *product_countries*, with two columns, *product_id* and *country*, with a foreign key from *product_id* referencing the *product* table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a safe way to do this kind of migration. You should instead:

1. [Create a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708090/3784008) to create a new column on the table:

```rb
class AddCountriesToProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :countries, :product, :string, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

2. Update your model to write to both columns concurrently, for example in an `after_save` callback so that changes to `country` are propagated to `countries`. At this point the two columns will not be completely in sync.
3. Save every product record (e.g., `Product.find_each(&:save!)`) so that the callback is triggered, pushing the values from `country` to `countries`. At this point the two columns will be completely in sync.
4. Update your app so that it no longer uses the `country` attribute and uses only the `countries` attribute. After this the two columns will no longer be in sync but `countries` will have the correct values.
5. Create a migration to drop the old column from the table:

```rb
class RemoveCountryFromProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :country, :product
  end
end
```

After you complete these steps you can begin using the `countries` column to store multiple strings.

A couple of notes:

- It's possible to do everything in a single migration if you don't mind locking the table and can handle downtime but for safe online migrations you don't want to do this.
- Your table is named `product` and not `products` which breaks Rails conventions. I've respected your table name in this example but you should consider fixing this.